# IndexedDB crashes when adding record with Image

Tags: javascript, base64, indexeddb

When I add an image (2-3mb base64 string) into my indexedDB it seems to crash with using the web app from an iPad/Safari (works fine in Chrome on Desktop).

```
InvalidStateError (DOM IDBDatabase Exception 11): Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': The database connection is closing.
```

Object trying to insert:

```
{
categoryNo: "C0103"
imageData: [{base64Image: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD…aUOUbIHsTUsVwQRZJF8/94dMe9TxKzK7ugwhK1s4su8T/2Q==", 
imageUploaded: false
}
```

I have used indexedDB for storing strings and it works fine, just when i try to add the object, with the base64 image.

```
bcUpdateIDB: function(sInspectionNo, sLineNo, sCategory, oRecord){
            var oController = this;
            var objectStore = oController.myDB.transaction("imageDB").objectStore("imageDB");

        var items = [];
        objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
            var cursor = event.target.result;
            if (cursor) {
                items.push(cursor.value);
                cursor.continue();
            } else {
                dataRecords = items;
                var oTransaction = oController.myDB.transaction(["imageDB"], "readwrite");
                var oDataStore = oTransaction.objectStore("imageDB");

                var recordFound = false;
                for (var i=0; i<dataRecords.length;i++){
                    var oDataRecord = dataRecords[i];
                    if(oDataRecord.lineNo === sLineNo && oDataRecord.inspectionNo === sInspectionNo && oDataRecord.category === sCategory){
                        recordFound = true;
                        oDataStore.delete(oDataRecord.id);
                        if(oRecord.imageData.length > 0){
                            oDataStore.add(oRecord);
                        }

                    }
                }

                if(!recordFound){
                    oDataStore.add(oRecord);
                }

            }
        };
```

In Safari it seems to hang on '.add()', this works in Chrome. Also, other add add/delete operations on a different transaction work fine.

Comment: You should be able to store blob and files as well, much better.

Answer (score 1):

This error is not related to *what* you are trying to store. This error is due to *when* you are trying to store an object in the database within your code. You did not post a sufficient amount of code to investigate and explain the problem.

Without knowing what the code looks like, my go to guess is the usual one. Do not use a global database variable. Become more familiar with how to write asynchronous javascript.

Edit:

Based on your revisions, my next guess is that you are starting a new transaction from within another transaction. Transactions automatically end after a certain period of time, after the point in time when there are no more requests processing that use that transaction. The error message indicates the transaction is inactive, which means you did some request call (request.add, request.remove, etc) too late, after the point in time the transaction ended.

There are many ways to fix it, but without getting two complicated, try the following. Whenever you are going to perform an unknown amount of requests, share the same transaction for everything. Use one transaction instead of two. This will keep the transaction alive.

Briefly:

```
bcUpdateIDB: function(sInspectionNo, sLineNo, sCategory, oRecord){
        var oController = this;
        var oTransaction = oController.myDB.transaction("imageDB", "readwrite");
        var objectStore = oTransaction.objectStore("imageDB");
// ...
        } else {
            dataRecords = items;
            // Now this reuses the one transaction instead of a new one
            var oDataStore = oTransaction.objectStore("imageDB");
```

As to why you only encounter the error sometimes? Well my guess is small string operations are faster so the transaction doesn't timeout, but with larger objects the requests are slower so the timeout actually happens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will add some information to the question. It seems the error I get back is actually when I try to do another operation on the indexed db, I can't figure out how to get the error from the .add(). Also, this works fine in Chrome, looks like it only happens in Safari

Comment: thanks again for the update, still getting the same issue - you think it could be with the base64 string? I will try to store a blob instead

Comment: @neeko no. 1) try using a single tx. 2) do not use a global database variable.

Comment: @neeko - I am a bit late to the game but did you solve the problem? Saved 2Mb image as Base64 inside IndexedDB and then tried displaying it back (IndexedDB > DOM) and it works in like 35 of 50 experiments. Browser/PWA just crashes on iPhone 7 (Safari 11.1), works 100% on Android (Samsung G8)...